# monodromy action on etale cohomology of proper smooth family over a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth curve, $\eta$ the generic point of $S$. $X$ is a smooth proper scheme over $S$.

My question is:

How to define an action of etale fundamental group $\pi_{1}(S)$ on the etale cohomology $H^{j}(X_{\overline \eta})$?

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer your question, but I hope it helps you forward. The keyword is *lisse $\ell$-adic sheaf*. Let $f \colon X \to S$ be the structure morphism. Then $R^{j}f_{*}\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ is a lisse $\ell$-adic sheaf on $S$. Moreover, the stalk at $\eta$ is isomorphic to $H^{j}(X_{\bar{\eta}})$.

Lisse $\ell$-adic sheaves are the analogues of local systems. There is a dictionary between local systems and representations of the (topological) fundamental group. The analogue extends to a dictionary between lisse $\ell$-adic sheaves and representations of the étale fundamental group.

In the topological picture, it is pretty easy to setup this dictionary. Given a local system $F$ on a space $Y$, a base point $y$, and a class of paths $\gamma \in \pi_{1}(Y,y)$, look at the stalk $F_{y}$. Any element $f \in F_{y}$ can be “followed” along $\gamma$, to give an element $\gamma \cdot f \in F_{y}$. (One can make this precise by pulling $F$ back to the unit interval along $\gamma$, and trivializing it there.

The dictionary in the $\ell$-adic case is more involved (after all the étale fundamental group does not really consist of classes of “paths”). Furthermore, the precise definition of lisse $\ell$-adic sheaves is already quite subtle. I would suggest keeping the analogue in mind, and accepting that the dictionary exists.

Q&A's on MO related to lisse sheaves and the $\pi_{1}$-representation:

- [A nice explanation of what is a smooth (l-adic) sheaf?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32478/a-nice-explanation-of-what-is-a-smooth-l-adic-sheaf/32717#32717)
- [Global sections of lisse sheaf as invariants of $\pi_1$-action](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77800/global-sections-of-lisse-sheaf-as-invariants-of-pi-1-action?rq=1)